# Converting a data frame to a motified list

Tags: r, list, dropdown

although there are alot of questions concering this topic; I can not seem to find the correct question answer. Therefore I am directing this question to you guys.

**The context:**
I've got a data set with alot of rows (+150K) with 32 corresponding columns. The second column is a document number. The document number is not a unique ID. So the date contains rows with mutiple rows with the same document number. I like to create a list of the document numbers. This list of document numbers contains another list with the corresponding rows with the same document numbers.

**For example:** 
Here is an example of the data (I included a `dput` output of the example below).

```
Document Number  Col.A          Col.B
A                random_56681   random_24984
A                random_78738   random_23098
A                random_48640   random_32375
B                random_96243   random_96927
B                random_72045   random_52583
C                random_19367   random_20441
C                random_96778   random_22161
C                random_48038   random_95644
C                random_62999   random_44561
```

Now here is what I am looking for. I need a list that contains the 3 documents (A, B, C). Each of these list needs to contain another list containing the corresponding rows. For example, the main list (lets say `my_list`) should have 3 lists A, B and C; each of the lists should contain respectively 3, 2 and 4 lists.

Hope I was clear enough in asking the question (if not please let me know).

Here you can find the example data:

```
structure(list(Document_Number = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Col.A = structure(c(4L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("random_19367", 
    "random_48038", "random_48640", "random_56681", "random_62999", 
    "random_72045", "random_78738", "random_96243", "random_96778"
    ), class = "factor"), Col.B = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 
    7L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 6L), .Label = c("random_20441", "random_22161", 
    "random_23098", "random_24984", "random_32375", "random_44561", 
    "random_52583", "random_95644", "random_96927"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split` like:

```
split(x, x$Document_Number)
#$A
#  Document_Number        Col.A        Col.B
#1               A random_56681 random_24984
#2               A random_78738 random_23098
#3               A random_48640 random_32375
#
#$B
#  Document_Number        Col.A        Col.B
#4               B random_96243 random_96927
#5               B random_72045 random_52583
#
#$C
#  Document_Number        Col.A        Col.B
#6               C random_19367 random_20441
#7               C random_96778 random_22161
#8               C random_48038 random_95644
#9               C random_62999 random_44561
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked so far! But I got an additional question. Lets say there is a column inserted in between the first and the second column with values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). Is there a posibility that I can unroll the first list and then the there are respectively 3,2,4 list sorted/split on the second (new column)?

Comment: You can use `lapply(split(x, x$Document_Number), function(y) split(y, y$secondColumn))`

Answer (score 2):

An option is `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_split(Document_Number)
```